# Show the value of the series: $\sum_{i=0}^n \left(1-(-1)^{\frac{i(i+1)}2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^i$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

So i have to show the value of the series

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \left(1-(-1)^{\frac{i(i+1)}2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^i$$

For this to exist it has to be convergent, so i checked if it is divergent using the limit test:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^n=1$$

Which clearly shows, that it is divergent. Now to the problem: Most/all of my fellow students claim to have a seriesvalue. Is the limit test not conclusive evidence for a series to be divergent?

Edit: I am sorry, I messed up. It should be a sum from n to infinity and not from i to n

Comment: There is a close parenthesis missing from your expression.  If you wish to type $(-1)^{\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}}$, type `$(-1)^{\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}}$`.

Comment: This is a sum not a series, its limit as $n\to \infty$ is a series. Please clarify that.

Comment: Also the limit is wrong, indeed $(1/3)^n \to 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I calculated the value of the series: $S=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(1-(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^k$

Form $S$ in the following way:

$S=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac 13\right)^k-\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left((-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^k=\frac {3}{2}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left((-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^k$

Separate the sum accordance with even and odd $k$:

If k even then $k=2m$, if odd then $k=2m+1$

Substitute them into S we get:

$S=\frac {3}{2}-\big(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{m}\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^{2m}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{3m+1}\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^{2m+1}\big)$

Repeat the separation for m values:

If m even then $k=2r$, if odd then $k=2r+1$

we have:

$S=\frac {3}{2}-\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty \big[\frac{(-1)^{2r}}{3^{4r}}+\frac{(-1)^{2r+1}}{3^{4r+2}}+\frac{(-1)^{6r+1}}{3^{4r+1}}\frac{(-1)^{6r+4}}{3^{4r+3}}\big]=\frac {3}{2}-\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty \big[\frac{1}{3^{4r}}\big(1-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{27}\big)\big]$

Summing the geometrical series and perform the simplifications we get that:

**$S=\frac{9}{10}$**

Using this method you can easily determine the value sum from k=0 to n.

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing with a sum not with a series, it is a series if we are dealing with its limit as $n\to \infty$.

To evaluate the sum note that

- $(-1)^{\frac{i(i+1)}2}=1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,\ldots$

then for $n=4k$

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \left(1-(-1)^{\frac{i(i+1)}2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^i=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac 13\right)^{1+4k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac 13\right)^{2+4k}$$

With reference to the series note that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^n=0$$

therefore we can't conclude form here that the series diverges.

Otherwise the series clearly converges since

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(1-(-1)^{\frac{i(i+1)}2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^i\le \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac 13\right)^{i}$$

and the RHS is a convergent geometric series.

Comment: $(-1)^{i(i+1)/2}$ is $1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1$ for $i$ from $0$ to $10$.  So it does not follow your even/odd rule.  It does have period $4$, so try doing four sums, based on $i\pmod{4}$.

Comment: @GEdgar Opssss...thanks I fix that!